# Using multiple 'is' variables in a single if statement

Tags: c#, if-statement, keyword

Assuming the following `if-statement`, when using the `is` keyword with multiple `OR` conditions, Is there a way to find out which condition passed the evaluation without having to check the values in separate or nested if-statements?

```
if (value is int xint
 || value is double xdouble
 || value is decimal xdecimal)
{
    // do with value
}
```

Comment: No. Use separate `if` statements, or a `switch` statement. In fact, the compiler won't let you access `xint`, `xdouble` or `xdecimal` inside the `if` statement at all, since the one you access might not have been assigned.

Comment: Actually you're right. Just when i wrote the statement and got no compiler errors i thought it might actually work.

Comment: I hate to say this because it sounds unhelpful, but a likely answer is not to do what you're trying to do. This method implies that `value` is an `object`. So the method starts with an object of unknown type and ends with three variables of different types, only one if which will have a value. Where possible it's better to make our code more certain of the types involved and avoid objects where we have to figure out what they are.